# Draw a circle on a figure Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I tried to modify this code in order to get a circle with coordinates instead of a rectangle.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{matlab.png}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        \draw[red,ultra thick] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. // Can you please: 1) Complete the code (minimal required preamble to compile), 2) Upload or link to a download of matlab.png? Thanks

Comment: Ok I edited my code. For the matlab.png it can be whatever you want so for example you can take : [link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Matlab_Logo.png/667px-Matlab_Logo.png)

Comment: Thanks. People are willing to help, so make it easy for them to do, next time ;-)

Comment: @Mo0nKizz in case the answer met your requirement it is customary to accept the answer by clicking the green check mark to the left and may also upvote the answer by clicking the upward pointing triangle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}};
        \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
            \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
            \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
            \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
            \draw[red,ultra thick] (0.62,0.65) circle (1cm);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! It works !

Comment: in case the answer met your requirement you may like to accept the answer by clicking the green check mark to the left and may also upvote the answer by clicking the upward pointing triangle

Comment: I suggest spending some time skimming through the PGF-manuals, especially the "Minimal introduction" at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf ;-)